# python: change datatype that includes .0

Tags: python, type-conversion

I am working with a dataframe, that unfortunately imports the column "ID" in the following format: 7.350943+e

I thought I fixed the issue with this code:

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%3.f' % x)
```

However, this only fixes the display, in the back-end it remains in this scientific format.

When I try to create a new column based on column ID and column source, I get the following:

```
df['Primary_key']=df['ID'].apply(str)+'_'+df['Source']

Name       ID        Source      Primary_key
John    782857635    email       782857635.0_email
```

What format do I need to change the datatype to in order to get rid of the .0?

```
df['ID'].values
array([782929635.0, 783063368.0, 782960457.0, ..., 783257941.0,
       783535550.0, nan], dtype=object)
```

I tried replacing it, in the Primary key, but it didn't work (there was no change to the dataframe)

```
df['Primary_key']= df['Primary_key'].str.strip().replace(".0_","_")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try something like:

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].apply(str).strip().replace(".0","")
```

Answer (score 1):

`int()` is what you seem to be looking for.

```
[int(i) for i in whateverList]
```